# Building and Linking the ANTLR4 C++ Runtime with CMake

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, antlr4

I'm trying to get started with making a compiler in C++, using ANTLR4 as a parser generator, but I'm inexperienced with CMake and don't understand the process of building and linking the ANTLR C++ runtime to my own application. I've been trying to follow [this tutorial](https://beyondtheloop.dev/Antlr-cpp-cmake/) which is linked in the ANTLR Git repo. I'm running Windows 10. My directory structure (minus some mess that I don't think is relevant) looks like this:

```
CMakeLists.txt
├───cmake
│       antlr4-generator.cmake.in
│       antlr4-runtime.cmake.in
│       ExternalAntlr4Cpp.cmake
│       FindANTLR.cmake
│
├───compiler-src
│       TestMain.cpp
│
├───Language1
│   │   Language1.g4
│   └───cpp
│           Language1.interp
│           Language1.tokens
│           Language1BaseListener.cpp
│           Language1BaseListener.h
│           Language1BaseListener.java
│           Language1Lexer.cpp
│           Language1Lexer.h
│           Language1Lexer.interp
│           Language1Lexer.java
│           Language1Lexer.tokens
│           Language1Listener.cpp
│           Language1Listener.h
│           Language1Listener.java
│           Language1Parser.cpp
│           Language1Parser.h
│           Language1Parser.java
└───lib
        antlr-4.9.2-complete.jar
```

(I manually generated the files in `Language1/cpp`)

My `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(project)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(ANTLR4CPP_JAR_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/antlr-4.9.2-complete.jar)
include(ExternalAntlr4Cpp)

include_directories(${ANTLR4CPP_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${ANTLR4CPP_LIBS})

message(STATUS "antlr4cpp libs at: ${ANTLR}")
message(STATUS "antlr4cpp includes are at: ${ANTLR4CPP_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

antlr4cpp_process_grammar(demo test_main ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Language1/Language1.g4)

include_directories(${antlr4cpp_include_dirs_test_main})

add_executable(TestMain compiler-src/TestMain.cpp ${antlr4cpp_src_files_test_main})

add_dependencies(TestMain antlr4cpp antlr4cpp_generation_test_main)

target_link_libraries(TestMain antlr4-runtime)
```

[`ExternalAntlr4Cpp.cmake` is from the ANTLR Git repo](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/0172e8661f97544627c74a65ae9f8cf8994e6afb/runtime/Cpp/cmake/ExternalAntlr4Cpp.cmake)

From what the tutorial says, my understanding is that my `CMakeLists.txt` should invoke the `ExternalAtlr4Cpp.cmake` file which will pull the latest version of the ANTLR source and build it.

I attempt to build by executing the following from the project root directory

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

I get the following output from CMake:

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30136.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30136.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Warning (dev) at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:2235 (message):
  Policy CMP0114 is not set: ExternalProject step targets fully adopt their
  steps.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0114" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  ExternalProject target 'antlr4_runtime' would depend on the targets for
  step(s) 'build_static' under policy CMP0114, but this is being left out for
  compatibility since the policy is not set.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/ExternalAntlr4Cpp.cmake:132 (ExternalProject_Add_StepTargets)
  CMakeLists.txt:10 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:2235 (message):
  Policy CMP0114 is not set: ExternalProject step targets fully adopt their
  steps.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0114" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  ExternalProject target 'antlr4_runtime' would depend on the targets for
  step(s) 'build_shared' under policy CMP0114, but this is being left out for
  compatibility since the policy is not set.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/ExternalAntlr4Cpp.cmake:149 (ExternalProject_Add_StepTargets)
  CMakeLists.txt:10 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- antlr4cpp libs at:
-- antlr4cpp includes are at:
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:18 (antlr4cpp_process_grammar):
  Unknown CMake command "antlr4cpp_process_grammar".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

When I comment out the offending line `antlr4cpp_process_grammar(demo test_main ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Language1/Language1.g4)` I get these errors instead

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:27 (add_dependencies):
  The dependency target "antlr4cpp" of target "TestMain" does not exist.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:27 (add_dependencies):
  The dependency target "antlr4cpp_generation_test_main" of target "TestMain"
  does not exist.
```

Any pointers as to what I'm missing here would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "my understanding is that my `CMakeLists.txt` should invoke the `ExternalAtlr4Cpp.cmake` file which will pull the latest version of the ANTLR source and build it". - No, you got it wrongly. Why don't follow the [README](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/tree/0172e8661f97544627c74a65ae9f8cf8994e6afb/runtime/Cpp/cmake#readme) located near the script?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for suggesting this, I followed the instructions and am able to do a clean build of a test application, but incremental builds fail with an error
`
CUSTOMBUILD : error : invalid path 'runtime/Cpp/runtime/thirdparty/utfcpp/' [C:\Users\redacted\project\build\antlr4_runtim
e.vcxproj]
CUSTOMBUILD : error : runtime/Cpp/runtime/thirdparty/utfcpp/: cannot add to the index - missing --add option? [C:\Users
\redacted\project\build\antlr4_runtime.vcxproj]
`
When it attempts to update `antlr4_runtime`. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: It is hard to suggest anything by looking into the error message without the code.